# Using Parameter on an HTML link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send a mail and I use IsBodyHtml for letting me edit my Mail on how it looks. I have to put a link on it and I use Parameter and the id. How can i include this in an href?

This is my example

```
  string body = "<table><tr><td>Please be informed that your employee <b>" + Session["Userfull"] + "</b> wants to send the no <b>" + id + " </b>. <br /> Please see attached the <b>"
        + "<a href=\'http://myproject/myproject.aspx'>" + "?Parameter=" + id 
        +" SF </a></b>.<br /><br /></td> </tr><tr><td>" +
        "If you need more details <b>" + Session["User"] + "</b>.</td></tr> </table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query string should be a part of link. Also i'll recommend to use String Format, so that code will look clean. Please find the modified code below

```
string bodyFormat = "<table><tr><td>Please be informed that your employee <b>{0}</b> wants to send the no <b>{1}</b>. <br /> Please see attached the <b><a href=\'http://myproject/myproject.aspx?Parameter={1}'> SF </a></b>.<br /><br /></td> </tr><tr><td>If you need more details <b>{2}</b>.</td></tr> </table>";
string body = string.Format(bodyFormat, Convert.ToString(Session["Userfull"]), id, Convert.ToString(Session["User"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example of href with query string parameters**

```
http://myproject/myproject.aspx?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3
```

It seems like you have string concatenation figured out, so just append your query string parameters to your anchor href.